# How to print an object in Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like:

```
{'string': u'abc', 'object': <DEMO.Detail object at 0xb5b691ac>}
```

How can I make it show the contents of the `DEMO.Detail object`'s `__dict__`, like so?

```
{'string': u'abc', 'object': {'obj_string': u'xyz', 'obj_object': {...}}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by $ **dict** of myobject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are the creator of `DEMO.Detail`, you could add `__repr__` and `__str__` methods:

```
class Detail:
    def __str__(self):
        return "string shown to users (on str and print)"
    def __repr__(self):
        return "string shown to developers (at REPL)"
```

This will cause your object to function this way:

```
>>> d = Detail()
>>> d
string shown to developers (at REPL)
>>> print(d)
string shown to users (on str and print)
```

In your case I assume you'll want to call `dict(self)` inside `__str__`.

If you do not control the object, you could setup a recursive printing function that checks whether the object is of a known container type (`list`, `tuple`, `dict`, `set`) and recursively calls iterates through these types, printing all of your custom types as appropriate.

There should be a way to override `pprint` with a custom [PrettyPrinter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter). I've never done this though.

Lastly, you could also make a custom [JSONEncoder](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) that understands your custom types. This wouldn't be a good solution unless you actually need a JSON format.

Comment: I think I will setup a recursive printing function to print this object. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Could prettyprint do it?

```
>>> import pprint
>>> a = {'foo':{'bar':'yeah'}}
>>> pprint.pprint(a)
{'foo': {'bar': 'yeah'}}
```

If your objects have `__repr__` implemented, it can also print those.

```
import pprint
class Cheetah:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "chirp"

zoo = {'cage':{'animal':Cheetah()}}
pprint.pprint(zoo) 

# Output: {'cage': {'animal': chirp}}
```

Comment: I don't have super high confidence in my answer, there is probably a better solution out there.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the code.  Not to bash your answer.  It just gives the same output with `print`.  May be a better example would show the difference

Comment: @akrun Yeah, I was expecting it to format it better, but looks just the same as print.

Comment: @Bemmu thank for your help, but i can't change the object inside "myobject". I want to print it out same as "myobject" without edit it.